# captcha displaying in a funny way

Tags: php, captcha

I have a captcha Code which works perfectly but I really dont know why it displays funny.
Can anyone help me figure out what might be the cause of this? Here is the code:

```
<?php
session_start();
$text = rand(10000,99999);
$_SESSION["vercode"] = $text;
$height = 25;
$width = 65;
$image_p = imagecreate($width, $height);
$black = imagecolorallocate($image_p, 0, 0, 0);
$white = imagecolorallocate($image_p, 255, 255, 255);
$font_size = 14;
imagestring($image_p, $font_size, 5, 5, $text, $white);
imagejpeg($image_p, null, 80);
?>
```

This is what is displays:

> kX’OýÓx£Ç> ñ=¨µÖ/b{ct÷¯½¬6É-Ã€iH¡ä csdòyäæcÆ^"Ö|7¥è¦­ss¤i™û%³‘¶>02q–Ú2q;A!p+Ÿ¢€:¿øX>'þÂþÈþÓÿDûöo™öx¾Ñö]Û¼?o›ågø7mÇËŒqF‡ñÄú•Ÿ¦j~M½·öWkx¤šÓÎ]²ù²™!Ü:ìeä“Ô“\¥QEQEÿÙ

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're missing the header. Add the following after `session_start()`:

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
```

The output will be something like:

[image]

Comment: Yes thats was the answer forsure it worked nicely . but what now it did , it hides the form , it does not display no more and the while page now is black

Comment: @JavaWest: Do you have error reporting turned on? Add this to the very top of your script: `ini_set('display_errors',1); 
 error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: No but Thanks my man I solve the problem now completely I wish I could upvote u , u saved my time

Comment: @JavaWest: Glad to have been of help :)

Answer (score 2):

When you're creating an image like this, you need to tell the browser what type of content you're wanting to display. Hence the reason:

```
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
```

is needed. Read the Wiki article on [MIME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME) if this confuses you. You'll also find that you'll need to specify the content type whenever you're generating other file types as well (for example: PDF files generated on the fly with PHP will require `header('Content-type: application/pdf');` )

Comment: Thanks for your contribution hey . and the explanation is very crucial